# Copiar todos os .jpg de subpastas para uma única pasta pelo cmd

Tags: cmd

Tenho uma pasta que nela tem 148 pastas contidas nela, e em cada dessas pastas elas possuem um arquivo `.jpg`. Preciso pegar todas esses `.jpg` e colocar em uma única pasta

[image]

[image: cada pasta tem pelo menos 1 .jpg]

consigo fazer isso no *Linux* assim

```
   `#!/bin/bash

for arquivo in `find Origem -name *.jpg`; 
   do mv "$arquivo" Destino;
    done;
```

mas não consigo reproduzir isso no *Windows*. Só o comando `find` que eu consigo reproduzir o mesmo resultado: `dir /S /B *.jpg`

Comment: Podia fazer pelo explorer mesmo. Pesquise *.jpg no canto superior esquerdo, que ele vai mostrar todos daquela pasta "para dentro". Aí você dá um control X (ou control C) e cola no destino.

Comment: mas eu preciso fazer isso de forma automática mas encontrei uma solução

for /r %d in (*.jpg) do copy /Y "%d" "C:\Users\IRINEU\Desktop\a\b"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui a solução

```
for /r %d in (*.jpg) do copy /Y "%d" "C:\Users\IRINEU\Desktop\a\b"
```

o parâmetro `/r` do `for` ele procura nas subpostas

declarei a a variável d assim -> `%d`

```
(*.jpg)
```

esse parâmetro procura todos os .jpg

Comment: +1 Perfeita a solução, marque como aceita para orientar os futuros visitantes

Comment: só posso fazer isso daqui dois dias se vc puder copiar e postar para eu aceitar

Comment: Aceite a sua mesmo daqui a dois dias, você merece receber os pontos pela postagem, não seria justo outro fazê-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Cria um arquivo .bat para isso, e insere o comando, será um tanto quanto artesanal, mas somente a parte de criar a listagem dos subdiretórios, por exemplo:

```
move c:\diretorio1\*.* g:\ /y
move c:\diretorio2\subdiretorio1\*.* g:\ /y
move c:\diretorio2\subdiretorio2\*.* g:\ /y
move c:\diretori3\subdiretorio1\*.* g:\ /y
```

E depois executa-o.

Comment: Se usar por exemplo o PHP em um servidor local, pode fazer recursão também

Comment: isso não fica muito viável mas achei um melhor agora pouco 

for /r %d in (*.jpg) do copy /Y  "%d" "C:\Users\IRINEU\Desktop\a\b"